# Есть ли способы автоматического перевода изображения в canvas / выделение области изображения?

Tags: html, html5, javascript

Добрый день.

Есть изображение пазла, [такое](http://static.freepik.com/darmowe-zdjecie/puzzle-clipart_431054.jpg), например. Задача состоит в том, чтобы при наведении на пазл срабатывало событие. Не на изображение, а именно на цветную часть.

Каким образом проще реализовать подобное, может, есть какие инструменты для преобразования изображения в canvas или выделения области изображения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Area Map](http://htmlbook.ru/html/area) ? ( http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/wr9d7/17/ )

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Елементарно из Image можно сделать Canvas:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```